# Select top most non-duplicated entry after ordering by other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to select the "top most" entry for each row with a duplicated column value.

Performing the following query -

```
SELECT *
FROM shop
ORDER BY shop.start_date DESC, shop.created_date DESC;
```

I get the result set -

```
+--------+---------+------------+--------------+
| row_id | shop_id | start_date | created_date |
+--------+---------+------------+--------------+
| 1      | 1       | 2017-02-01 | 2017-01-01   |
| 2      | 1       | 2017-01-01 | 2017-02-01   |
| 3      | 2       | 2017-01-01 | 2017-07-01   |
| 4      | 2       | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-01   |
+--------+---------+------------+--------------+
```

Can I modify the `SELECT` so that I only get back the "top rows" for each unique shop_id -- in this case, `row_id`s 1 and 3. There can be **1..n** number of rows with the same `shop_id`.

Similarly, if my query above returned the following order, I'd want to only `SELECT` `row_id`s 1 and 4 since those would be the "top most" entries each `shop_id`.

```
+--------+---------+------------+--------------+
| row_id | shop_id | start_date | created_date |
+--------+---------+------------+--------------+
| 1      | 1       | 2017-02-01 | 2017-01-01   |
| 2      | 1       | 2017-01-01 | 2017-02-01   |
| 4      | 2       | 2017-01-01 | 2017-07-01   |
| 3      | 2       | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-01   |
+--------+---------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: could there be same `row_id`s for different `shop_id`s?

Comment: row 2 has different dates to row 1 (so row 2 is NOT a duplicate of row 1), why is row 2 excluded?

Comment: @potashin I would normally make this assumption, and there is no penalty for not making it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: there is actually - the code being superfluous at least. also the assumption can't be confirmed by the sample data, so it is better to ask

Comment: @potashin Data can change over time, and I can readily imagine making this assumption and the query breaking later on.  But good on you for thinking of a reduced way to write the query.

Comment: @potashin `row_id` is the PK on the table. If I understand your question correctly, the same `row_id` cannot be tied to a different `shop_id`

Comment: @macbombe: yes, this is exactly what I was asking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a subquery:

```
select s.* 
from shop s 
where s.row_id = (
  select row_id 
  from shop 
  where shop_id = s.shop_id 
  order by start_date desc, created_date desc 
  limit 1
)
```

Mind the assumption of `row_id` being uniq for each `shop_id` in this query example.

[**Demonstration**](http://rextester.com/XGE58558)

Or like this:

```
select t.*
from shop t
join (
 select t2.shop_id, t2.start_date, max(t2.created_date) as created_date 
 from shop t2
 join (
   select max(start_date) as start_date, shop_id
   from shop
   group by shop_id
 ) t3 on t3.shop_id = t2.shop_id and t3.start_date = t2.start_date
 group by t2.shop_id, t2.start_date
) t1 on t1.shop_id = t.shop_id and t.start_date = t1.start_date and t.created_date = t1.created_date
```

Mind that in case there can be records with the same `start_date` *and* `created_date` for the same `shop_id` you would need to use another `group by s.shop_id, s.start_date, s.created_date` in the outer query (adding `min(row_id)` with other columns listed in the `group by` in `select`)

[**Demonstration**](http://rextester.com/MHL68582)

Comment: I added a slightly different example that I cannot get to work with your demo.

Comment: @macbombe: updated

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using limit?

Comment: @macbombe: yes, it is

Answer (score 0):

Try joining to a subquery which finds the "top" rows for each `shop_id`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM shop t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT shop_id, MIN(row_id) AS min_id
    FROM shop
    GROUP BY shop_id
) t2
    ON t1.shop_id = t2.shop_id AND
       t1.row_id = t2.min_id
ORDER BY
    t1.start_date DESC,
    t1.created_date DESC;
```

[image]

### Demo